# Securing REST-based WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, security, authentication

I'm looking for a way to secure my WCF service using http and simple username-password authentication, **without using certificates**.
The service is consumed by an Android device so I can't use the .NET Proxy generated classes.
I've read about basic HTTP authentication but haven't found an easy way to implement this method.

Comment: When you mention HTTP, does it imply you'll actually be using HTTPS (SSL)?

Comment: @sixto-saez As I've mentioned, I'm not using any certificates.

Comment: In that case, you don't have *any* security for your application at all. Anyone that can view the HTTP request between the device and your server will have the credentials in clear text. SilverNinja's solution relies HTTPS to be secure as stated in the MSDN article and WCF will **not** support username/password validation in clear text out-of-the-box.

Comment: I don't need full security for my service at the moment. the only thing I need for now is a to limit access to the service methods by authenticating the user.

Comment: Famous last words... :) Good luck to you and your potential users 'cause you'll need it!!

Comment: I'm working on a simple project, not even for someone or a company and security is not my top concern at this early stage. I just want to know how I can authenticate the user before he can use the service.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11150/discussion-between-adir-and-sixto-saez)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found ASP.NET Web API, seems like a better solution for REST-based Services than WCF.

Comment: What was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [MSDN custom Username/Password validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565.aspx) for WCF? It relies on the [`serviceCredentials`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731370.aspx) configuration and implementing a [`UsernamePasswordValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.selectors.usernamepasswordvalidator.aspx).